# conflicting issue is coming when we are adding networkmanager in yocto build

Tags: linux-kernel, yocto, openembedded

We are using yocto to build a image.
I tried to add  IMAGE_INSTALL_append = "modemmanager networkmanager" in /build/conf/local.conf.
But i am getting some errors :-
package networkmanager-1.10.6-r0.aarch64 conflicts with connman provided by connman-1.35-r0.aarch64.
So I try to remove connman and ofono ,change in local.conf.

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_remove = "connman connman-client"
IMAGE_INSTALL_remove = "ofono ofono-tests"
```

but it is not happening , same error i am getting
how to remove connman and ofono ?

Comment: connman or ofono may be part of DISTRO_FEARURES, so just IMAGE_INSTALL_remove will not remove them. Can you check from which recipe or how these(connman or ofono) is building using bitbake -e image

Comment: PACKAGE_EXCLUDE = "connman ofono" in your local.conf might bring interesting answers when trying to build. It should fail for a few packages, highlighting where those dependencies were added, from there you might understand better how to remove those from your build.

Answer (score 1):

Inside  networkmanager .bb file changed  # RCONFLICTS_${PN} = "connman"  to
RREPLACES_${PN} = "connman" , it replaces connman and install networkmanager
package.
it works for me.